# Is the Land of Ooo really a post apocalyptic Earth?

Tags: analysis, adventure-time

I have heard a lot of theories spout about how the world of Adventure Time is actually based on a Post-Apocalypic Earth that has adapted to nuclear fallout, changing all living things with what they know as 'magic'.

Granted I'm not that far into the episodes, but is there any real merit to these claims and is there specific hints one should be looking out for that support this theory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Adventure Time wiki](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Land_of_Ooo):

> Pendleton Ward, the creator of Adventure Time, has stated in an interview that the Land of Ooo is actually a post-apocalyptic Earth, the result of a global disaster called the Mushroom War, hence the ruined pieces of modern technology scattered across the land.

Comment: There is also the episode Holly Jolly Secrets it shows the Ice King in pre-apocalypic Earth.